# Should a bumped old question ever become a '[greatest hit] from previous weeks'?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, newsletter, question-activity

I've noticed this behaviour a few times the past weeks in the weekly newsletter. A person comments or posts an answer on an old question that was once popular and it becomes one of the two *greatest hits from previous weeks* in the newsletter.

Doesn't *from previous weeks* imply that the question shouldn't be older than a few weeks? The name sounds a bit odd to me when it's about a question that's more than a year old.

Example from this week's newsletter: [Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7637144/319611).

Is this meant to be behave like this or is this a bug in the newsletter generator?

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't from previous weeks imply that the question shouldn't be older than a few weeks?

The only thing I infer from "from previous weeks" is that it's not from *this* week.  Any previous week should be included.

Comment: While that is technically true, that would raise the question why it's called 'greatest hits from previous weeks' instead of something along the lines of 'greatest all time hits'.

Comment: The current algorithm also seems to favour questions with recent activity over questions with no recent activity, which again implies that the questions are in a way current. This however is often just caused by a new answer to a question that's not particularly useful anymore.

Comment: It's called 'greatest hits from previous weeks' because it's a weekly newsletter. Everything else is from the past week.